# What date format is the following in? 439189200

Tags: xml

I am working with a 3rd party api that gives nfl player information.  One of the attributes is "birthdate" and it comes across as all numbers (ex. 439189200, 431154000).  I am not familiar with this formatting, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: (This is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it's UNIX timestamp: for example, `439189200` stands for `2nd December 1983 05:00:00 AM UTC`.

Comment: thanks, just stumpled on that myself.  not used to seeing dates represented like this in XMl

Comment: @user257655 - It's actually a fairly common representation, especially in XML.